# Is a sheaf, which is flasque when restricted to any open affine necessarily flasque?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

This is something I got stuck thinking about while trying to solve a problem in Hartshorne: if $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi coherent sheaf on a noetherian scheme $X$ such that $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is flasque for all open affine $U\subset X$ will $\mathcal{F}$ then be flasque?

The problem I'm working on is III.3.6 (b) which says that any injective object of $QCoh(X)$ is flasque. I was able to prove the hint which says that for any injective sheaf $\mathcal{J}$ on $X$ and any open $U\subset X$ the restriction $\mathcal{J}|_U$ is an injective sheaf on $U$.

Comment: Which problem and what have you tried? (I don't think this particular claim is necessary to solve any of the exercises in Hartshorne, which is good because the obvious strategy of attempting to use the sheaf condition runs in to immediate difficulties - you'd want to apply the four lemma, but you're missing the requisite injectivity condition.)

Comment: Yes I think I tried to use some version of the five lemma but didn't get anywhere. I've also tried to prove this claim directly by gluing together elements but it does not seem to work either. It's for problem  III.3.6 (d)! I edited my questions too.

Comment: Yes. Flasque is a local property.

Comment: @Justauser please consider expanding your comment as an answer below.

Comment: For the OP, I think you can do the problem a bit faster by embedding your injective sheaf in a flasque sheaf and then using the splitting lemma. But that's not exactly an answer to the question you're actually asking here, so I'll leave it as a comment for now.

Comment: Thanks Kreiser, that's seems like a much quicker approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand my comment that being flasque is local. If $\mathcal F$ is a locally flasque sheaf over (a topological space) $X$, let $U\subset X$ be an open subset, and $a\in\mathcal F(U)$. We want to show that $a$ can be extended to be a glocal section over $X$. By Zorn's lemma, we may pick a maximal extension $\tilde{a}$ of $a$. If the domain $V$ of $a$ is not $X$, pick $x_0\in X\setminus V$, then by $\mathcal F$ is locally flasque, pick an open Flasque neighborhood $W$ of $x_0$, $\tilde{a}_{W\cap V}$ can be extended to a section $\tilde{a}'\in\mathcal F(W)$, but now glue $\tilde{a}$ and $\tilde{a}'$, we get a strict extension of $\tilde{a}$.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot!